# Twitter API widget

Tags: orange

I am using the Twitter API. The Orange widget for Twitter works fine if we do a search by content. However, it throws an error if you search by author.

[image]

```
The error is: Api error(Twitter error response status code = 401)
```

Comment: i had the same issue, i had generated new api key and pasted it in orange, and issue was solved

Answer (score 0):

It seems **Unauthorized** issue. Did you pass in the Twitter key and secret?

Comment: Yes, I did put the right access and secret keys. I could download tweets by selecting content in the search by dropdown box.

Comment: I may have found the reason. If you search for @ Hillary Clinton, or @ Donald Trump, it gives and API error. But a new thing has now come up, if I put my @own name in the query, it does a search, but does not disconnect. The search status remains at 100%, and freezes. On stopping it, there is no output. I guess there is some issue with the widget, that needs to be sorted out. Request early resolution from orange.

Comment: I have not used orange widget much.. but is there a way for you to limit the depth of search for @ mentions or is it possible to check with hashtags and post the error

Comment: You can limit the number of tweets that you want by ticking the max no of tweets box and entering a value. As for the hashtags, I have no idea of this.

Comment: Can you try with limiting the number of tweets, start with a count of 100 or 1000. It should not freeze.
Am just mentioning various debugging options to find the root cause

Comment: Sunil, I tried all the option, It just freezes. Any help someone please.

Comment: I would try to look reproducing your problem. Will get back

Comment: Sunil, I did something out of the box. The rolled back the text add on version to 0.5.0 from 0.5.2. It worked. However, It would be great if you could identify the bug. Technically, I have found some solutions ;-).

Comment: that's great to know @Arvind, back versioning solved your problem. Yes, I would also try

Comment: Oop Sunil, I just realized that I posted the comment without checking for the grammar and spellings. My bad, my English indeed sounded atrocious. As for the update, rolling back has indeed helped. Things are working fine now.